# Is mem::forget(mem::uninitialized()) defined behavior?

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior, unsafe

In [mutagen](https://github.com/llogiq/mutagen), I'm injecting various
mutations in the code. One thing I'd like to mutate is the pattern
`if let Ok(x) = y { .. }`. However, this poses quite the challenge, as I
cannot know the type of `y` – the user could have built their own enum with an
unary `Ok` variant. I can still opportunistically mutate it for cases where we
actually have a `Result` whose error type implements `Default` using a trait
that looks like the following simplified:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

pub trait Errorer {
    fn err(self, mutate: bool) -> Self;
}

impl<X> Errorer for X {
    default fn err(self, _mutate: bool) -> Self {
        self
    }
}

impl<T, E> Errorer for Result<T, E>
where
    E: Default,
{
    fn err(self, mutate: bool) -> Self {
        if mutate {
            Err(Default::default())
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Alas, there aren't that many errors which implement `Default`, so this is
not too useful. Even an implementation for `Result<T, Box<Error>>` would give
us more bang for the buck (and be completely possible). However, given that I
don't care much about code actually *inspecting* the error, I wonder if I could
do a general implementation by extending the mutation of the above code to

```
match Errorer::err(y, mutation) {
    Ok(x) => { .. }
    Err(x) => { mem::forget(x); }
}
```

and have `err` return `Err(mem::uninitialized())` when mutating – so is this
behavior safe? Note: I'm returning `Err(mem::uninitialized())` from a method,
only to `mem::forget` it later. I see no way this could panic, so we should
assume that the value will be indeed forgotten.

Is this defined behavior or should I expect nasal demons?

Comment: Something that comes to mind: Rust is free to manipulate how it represents enums based on the representation of its variants' payloads (*i.e.* the trick that makes `Option<Box<T>>` the same size as `Box<T>`).  I'm not aware of any layout optimisations that affect `Result`, but I also see no reason they couldn't be added in future.  If that were the case, `mem::uninitialized` could leave the `E` value in an invalid state that changes how the `Result` is interpreted.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. So there is no guarantee of defined behavior when it comes to putting invalid states into enums.

Comment: Not sure whether it's the case yet, but `Result<T, !>` could and (someday) should have the same layout as `T`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, this is not defined behavior, at least not for all types.  (I can't tell how your code would be called as part of mutation, so I don't know if you have control over the types here, but the generic `impl` sure makes it look like you do not.)  That's demonstrated by the following piece of code:

```
#![feature(never_type)]
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    unsafe { mem::forget(mem::uninitialized::<!>()) }
}
```

If you [run this on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=675ba20c51ad31461e2c12b2e1d46a21&version=nightly&mode=release), you will see the program die with a SIGILL.  The ASM output shows that LLVM just optimized the entire program to immediate SIGILL because of the way it uses a value of the uninhabited type `!`:

```
playground::main:
    ud2
```

Generally speaking, it is near impossible to correctly use `mem::uninitialized` in generic code, see e.g. [this issue of `rc::Weak`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48493).  For this reason, that function is in the process of being [deprecated and replaced](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1892).  But that won't help you here; what you want to do is just outright illegal for `Result<T, !>`.

Comment: *LLVM just optimized the entire program to immediate SIGILL* — now that's efficient code generation.